# in my javascript file, which executes first, initialization code or code in an $(document).ready() event

Tags: javascript, jquery, execution, document-ready

A project I am working on has some initialization code (not in any function) and some code in a jQuery $(document).ready() event. Which code executes first? Why? I'd also like to know why it might have been written that way? Thanks. For example:

```
'use strict';
let inputs = [];
function func(){};
function func2(){};
$(document).ready(function(){
  const a = 1;
  func2();
})
```

Comment: what executes first? unclear what you are asking

Comment: sorry I was unclear. in this example which executes first: the let inputs= [ ] statement or the statements in the document.ready event const a = 1 and func2()?

Answer (score 1):

The **ready()** method is used to make a function available after the document is loaded. Whatever code you write inside the **$(document ).ready()** method will run once the page DOM is ready to execute JavaScript code.

> In this code fun2() will call first after the document is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

The code will execute from the top down: `'use strict';` executes first, followed by `let inputs = [];`, etc.

Note that executing your function definitions `function func(){};` and `function func2(){};` don't actually *call* the functions at that point.

Once the document has loaded, it calls the anonymous function passed to `$(document).ready()` which executes `const a = 1;` and finally calls `func2();`.